# Best way to query posts and order by relevancy to query

Tags: wp-query, user-meta, order

I want to query a custom post type that has 100+ associated categories. The query will be based on values in the current user meta, specifically, the user will have preselected categories they want to see.

What is the best way to do the query that: returns all posts that match at least one category while ordering by post with the most number of categories matching the user preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be cleanly expressed in WP query API. YOu can query for posts matching *all* of terms in a set or *any* of terms in a set, but there is no concept of *how many* terms matched.

You would need to write either:

1. Very custom SQL for the query you want which will implement the counting.
2. Query loosely everything that matches and do the coun on PHP side after getting results.